# Open Cordova iOS external links in webview like an iFrame

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

I'm building an iOS app using cordova that basically opens news links to external sites. However iFrames don't seem to want to play nice on iOS. Is it possible to use UIWebView much like an iframe? I want to just embed a box on my app page so I can keep my apps header navigation and such. Instead right now opening links just pops the page up over everything.